# How to pass error message from bean to form in Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, hibernate-validator

I have simple application where I am using validation (which works perfectly) however I have issues passing error message back to form. In examples I have seen it looks like it is "magically" passed back to form without manually setting any attribute or whatsoever.

This is my controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createMember", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showContacts() {

    return new ModelAndView("createMember", "command", new Member());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/createMember", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addContact(@ModelAttribute("member")
                        @Valid Member member, BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("createMember", "command", member);
    }     
    mba.addMember(member);         
    return getPages();
}
```

And this is my createMember.jsp :

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<html>
<head>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/core/jquery.1.10.2.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/core/jquery.autocomplete.min.js" />"></script>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/core/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<form:form method="post" action="createMember.html">

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="firstName" value="${member.firstName}" /></td> 
        <form:errors path="firstName" cssclass="error"></form:errors>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="lastName" value="${member.lastName}" /></td>
        <form:errors path="lastName" cssclass="error"></form:errors>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="email1">Email</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input value="${member.email1}" path="email1" /></td>
        <form:errors path="email1" cssclass="error"></form:errors>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  

</form:form>

<a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}"> Back to main page </a> 

</body>
</html>
```

I am using Spring 3.2.2, Tomcat 7, hibernate-validator

Validation class :

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
public class Member {

    private int memberID;
    private int gender;

    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty @Email
    private String email1;

    //...getters and setters here
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide the Member class? It would be useful to see the validation annotations that you are using in that class.

Comment: I added that, however how I said, validation itself works perfectly (if it has errors, the if(result.hasErrors()) is true and is executed]

Comment: This is a strange one, i've compared some code I have that does a similar thing and I can't see much difference. Are you including '<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>' in your jsp file?
Also, try changing the members from private to public, or create public accessors for them. (i am grasping at straws here :] )

Comment: It should works without adding anything

Comment: @NickWeedon - I edited my jsp file to have everything I have, not just that form. Also I have public accessors for them, storing value with "value={member.something}" works perfectly too.

Comment: I do see that the form 'action' attribute in the jsp file is 'createMember.html' shouldn't this be '/createMember'?
I know that the post code is executing but still, it might be worth correcting this just in case it is confusing spring.

Comment: Failing that, I would turn on tracing at this point. I have a log4j trace file that you can use if you don't have a configuration file already :)

Comment: @NickWeedon - yeah, true, tx :) (unfortunatelly, magic didnt happen, so it does not solved this program :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `@ModelAttribute("command")` instead of `@ModelAttribute("member")` in your controller class.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't solve this directly but here is a log4j config file that might help. Just make sure it gets deployed to WEB-INF/classes inside your WAR file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
     <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

      <!--  Log levels:
          ALL,
          TRACE,
          DEBUG,
          INFO,
          WARN,
          ERROR,
          FATAL
       -->

    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
  <logger name="org.springframework">
      <level value="TRACE" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.springframework.context">
      <level value="TRACE" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.springframework.http">
      <level value="TRACE" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.springframework.web">
      <level value="TRACE" />
  </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="TRACE" />
    </logger>

  <root>
    <priority value ="TRACE" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Also examine your pom.xml or gradle config file. Spring version mismatches can cause all sorts of weird problems.

Comment: That is nice that you are trying to help. But you know that if you are sure it's not a good idea to post answer sir. You can read about good answer here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Your form has not backed with the model (To do validation Spring must know which field in models are belongs to which fields in the view). To do that you need to add `modelAttribute` attribute is your Spring form. So these are the lines you need to worry.

**In controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createMember", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addContact(@ModelAttribute("member") @Valid Member member, BindingResult result)
```

The value you gives to `@ModelAttribute("member")` should be mentioned in  the form.

**In view**

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="member" action="createMember.html">
```

If you don't want mentions the `modelAttribute="whateveryournamehere"` you should use `@ModelAttribute("command")` as, in the Controller. Then you don't want to use `modelAttribute="command"`.